# Is .NET 7 native AOT supported macOS?

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, ahead-of-time-compile, native-aot

There is no information about the macOS platform. Has AOT supported it, or is there any plan?

Answer (score 5):

At time of writing, the only supported targets according to MS docs are Windows and Linux - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/#platformarchitecture-restrictions

Screenie for posterity:
[image]

This doesn't answer your question about whether there are plans to support it on MacOS - maybe someone else has that info.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the official [docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/#platformarchitecture-restrictions) Native AOT support only on Windows and Linux for .NET 7:

> The following table shows supported compilation targets when targeting .NET 7.

| Platform | Supported architecture |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | x64, Arm64 |
| Linux | x64, Arm64 |

But based on the issues/discussions in the github repo (for example [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61231#issuecomment-1235385283), [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/75005) and especially [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64337) one) the working is going on for future releases to support Native AOT on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the mac platform is [on the way](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61231)

Answer (score 0):

As of .NET 8, AOT compiled binaries for macOS are supported for both arm64 and x64 architectures. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net8plus%2CmacOS#platformarchitecture-restrictions

Do some [project setup first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net8plus%2CmacOS#publish-native-aot-using-the-cli).

Example invocation:

```
dotnet publish -r osx-arm64 -c Release
```